# Missing Callback Error Prevents Script from Proceeding

Tags: node.js, request, fs, cheerio

I'm currently writing a script that crawls a number of sites and dumps the results in a mongodb. When I run a bulk seed file (so I don't have to run each crawler and individual seed manually), The first crawler completes, but the following error hangs, preventing the rest of the steps from occuring.

```
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, open '../cache/nfHitters.json'
```

Below is my crawler code. Is there a way to remove this Error completely (or are there best practices I'm missing to prevent this from occuring all together)?

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require("request");
var json = require("json");
var fs = require('fs');

request('website-I-Am-Crawling.com', 
    function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html)
            var variable = $('script')[3].children[0].data
            var data = variable.substring(variable.indexOf("= ")+2, variable.indexOf(";"))
            fs.writeFile('../cache/nfHitters.json', data, error)
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`error` is not a function, but you're passing it as the callback argument to `fs.writeFile()`. If there is no error, `error` is `null`, so that is why you see that particular message. If it was some other non-`null`/`undefined` value, you would have gotten a type error thrown instead.

Try this:

```
fs.writeFile('../cache/nfHitters.json', data, function(err) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: when giving it a callback argument, the server hangs on the new callback (the function which console logs 'Theres an error'). So I guess my question is it defaulting to the callback, rather than completing the crawler action and moving on to the next script?